Representing a function that is measurable with respect to a completed sigma algebra
The following is an assertion from the book Discrete-Parameter Martingales by J. Neveu, at the start of the first chapter.
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $\mathcal{B}$ be a sub-sigma-algebra of $\mathcal{A}$ and let $\tilde{\mathcal{B}}$ be generated by $\mathcal{B}$ and the sets in $\mathcal{A}$ with zero probability. Let $f$ be a real valued $\mathcal{A}$-measurable function. It is claimed that $f$ is $\tilde{\mathcal{B}}$-measurable if and only if it is a.s. equal to a $\mathcal{B}$ measurable function.
The if direction is clear to me, but I cannot figure out why the only if direction is true. What seems to be a strategy is to first prove a more concrete expression for $\tilde{\mathcal{B}}$, and then approximate $f$ by step-functions, which are almost surely equal to $\mathcal{B}$-measurable step functions. Any help would be appreciated.

Isn't this a standard argument where you start with indicator functions, proceed with simple measurable functions (finite linear combinations with positive coefficients), positive measurable functions (as increasing limits of simple functions) and, finally, arbitrary measurable functions by decomposing into positive and negative parts?

@Jochen indeed, it is called standard machinery. But first we need a representation for $\tilde{\mathcal{B}}$, which I haven't managed.

One possibility is to show $\tilde{\mathcal B}={A\in\mathcal A: P(A\Delta B)=0$ for some $B\in\mathcal B}$ where $A\Delta B$ is the symmetric difference.
